# My code is below. It's working fine, but i want it not to display form again after the errors were found. How can it be done?

Tags: php

My code is below. It's working fine, but i want it not to display form again after the errors were found. How can it be done?
This is a single page, username validation program i just want to know why form is displayed again after, and how will i solve it.

```
   <?php require'function.php'; ?>
<?php
    $errors = array();
    $username = "";
    $password = "";
    $msg = "Please Log in.";
  ?>
<?php if (isset($_POST['submit']))
{
    $username = $_POST['username'];
    $password = $_POST['password'];

    if($username != "rish" && $password != "password"){
        $msg = "Try again.";
      $errors['cred'] = "Wrong Credentials.";
    }
 }
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Single Page Form</title>
</head>
<body>
<?php
     echo display_error($errors);
     ?>
<?php echo $msg ?>
<form action="singleform.php" method="post">
    Username:  <input type="text" name="username" value="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($username); ?>"><br>
    Password:  <input type="password" name="password" value="<?php echo "" ?>"><br>
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: add an if statement to check whether `$errors` is empty or not, and either display errors, or do whatever you want. Not sure why you wouldn't want the form to show again if there were errors, seems if there were errors you'd want them to try again

Comment: You may want to see [this](http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/13353/password-in-file-php) about storing passwords in PHP files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do verifying if the $_POST data is empty. If was not empty, the users just load the page.

Can be do like code below:

```php
<?php if(empty($_POST)):?>
    <form action="singleform.php" method="post">
            Username:  <input type="text" name="username" value="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($username); ?>"><br>
            Password:  <input type="password" name="password" value="<?php echo "" ?>"><br>
            <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit">
        </form>
    <?php endif;?>
```

Comment: i didnt know the if/endif syntax. Thanx

Answer (score 0):

user isset ,, if the error initializes then it won't be displayed

```
<? if (!isset($errors['cred'])) { ?>
<form action="singleform.php" method="post">
Username:  <input type="text" name="username" value="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($username); ?>">  <br>
Password:  <input type="password" name="password" value="<?php echo "" ?>"><br>
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
<?php } ?>
```